# php code to display none?

Tags: php

I'm sure this is fairly simple but I really don't get php is there a way to have the below code to display none if there's no url details entered?

```
    <div class="details">       
        <h3>web</h3>
        <div>URL: <span><a href="<?=$website_url?>"><?=$website_url?></a></span></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in an [if statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).

```
<? if($website_url): ?>
    <div class="details">       
            <h3>web</h3>
            <div>URL: <span><a href="<?=$website_url?>"><?=$website_url?></a></span></div>
     </div>
<? endif;?>
```

**EDIT**

This might be better:

```
<?php if($website_url){ ?>
        <div class="details">       
                <h3>web</h3>
                <div>URL: <span><a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>"><?php echo $website_url; ?></a></span></div>
         </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: -1: in principle, yes, but short tags? The alternate control structure syntax? Neither are deprecated but at best they are contentious.

Comment: He used short tags in his question, I just adapted his code style as I saw it. He is free to adapt it.

Comment: @symcbean: Actually, there are quite a lot of developers who use alternate control structure syntax when mixing HTML and PHP code like this.

Comment: Wordpress uses alternate control structure syntax. I think it looks a lot nicer when mixing HTML and PHP, easier to read. The following question seems to suggest short tags are not too bad either -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: Many thanks Mind Fuzz, (appropriate name as that's what my mind turns into whenever I try to learn PHP) that did the trick.

Comment: haha, glad it helped. Be sure to mark the answer as accepted (little tick under the up/down voting)

Comment: ah, that's what's that is... d'oh!

Comment: No probs, I note you're a new member. Learn the ropes and reap the benefits of a great community.